# Slider (Carousel) Bootstrap, Como mudar a aninmação

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

estou começando agora a mexer tanto com site quanto com bootstrap, estou utilizando o wordpress tbm. Ok a minha duvida é a seguinte, eu gostaria de saber se é possível mudar a animação padrão de transição que vem com o menu padrão do bootstrap e adicionar uma outra animação durante as transições de 1 slider para o outro.

Analisando o HTML creio que a parte que cuida da animação é essa parte do codigo.

```
<a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
```

> data-slide="prev"

pq vendo uns slider com animações de outros sites, vejo que em vez de "Data-Slide" ta "Data-Animation" ou algo assim.

Então... tem como cuidar dessa animação apenas por HTML, ou terei de usar elementos css ou até o java-script.

Desde já obrigado.

Código do slide do site do bootstrap

```html
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="..." alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="..." alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
    ...
  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Até dá, mas seu código ali no editor está incompleto e não dá para saber direito como mudar a animação.

Dá para colocar um ID em cada slide e modificar eles com javascript: 

var x = document.getElementById('demo1').innerHTML = "Teste1"
var y = document.getElementById('demo2').innerHTML = "Teste2"
var z = document.getElementById('demo3').innerHTML = "Teste3"
document.getElementById('demo1').innerHTML = x
document.getElementById('demo2').innerHTML = y
document.getElementById('demo3').innerHTML = z

Comment: hm... n utilizei javascript ainda no meu site, então essa adição so vai poder ser feita através de javascript ? PS: está incompleto pq n tem os arquivos do bootstrap, vou tentar adicionar

Comment: Acredito que sim, é o mais indicado. Mas será coisa simples de se fazer com javascript.

Comment: não estou conseguindo encontrar aonde editar a publicação, para adicionar o css xD, bem obrigado de qualquer jeito vou ir atras de ver mais sobre como utilizar o javascript então OBRIGADO!!!